# Am I using document incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I have recently switched from using the jQuery library in favour of raw Javascript to gain a deeper understanding of the language (though you will notice jQuery is running in the background to support legacy functions).

I am trying to set up a click event using `.addEventListener()` to a btn but am getting the following error in my console:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: pleaseWork.addEventListener is not a function
    at eval (eval at globalEval (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:16:9)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at z (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.send (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.n._evalUrl (jquery.min.js:4)
```

I am unsure as to why I cannot create a `function()` on `'click'` using the following Javascript. All my class names are correct, so I have only added my Javascript and not markup.

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var fieldsets = form.getElementsByTagName('fieldset');

var pleaseWork = document.getElementsByClassName('js primary medium btn');

var fieldsetCount = 0;

for (var i = 0, length = fieldsets.length; i < length; i++) {
    if(fieldsets[i].type == 'fieldset') {
        fieldsetCount++;
    };
};

console.log(fieldsetCount);

pleaseWork.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Boom!');
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements (sort of an array), not a single element

Comment: Are you saying if I add an id to my btn and use `getElementById()` my problem will be solved?

Comment: Using/not-using jQuery is not about understanding JavaScript the **language**, it's about understanding web browser native APIs.

Comment: if you expect more than one element in the result, you need to change the code to loop through the returned list. Otherwise, use [0] - or `getElementById` works just as well (even better)

Comment: an alternative, widely supported method would be to use `querySelector` (to get a single result) or `querySelectorAll` (to get a list of results) ... the arguments to those functions are very much like what you're used to with jQuery

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX this has solved my issues.

Comment: you got an error in `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName() returns an array. 
Arrays do not have de method .addEventListener()

Comment: It returns an array-like object, not an actual array. (But you are of course correct that it has no `addEventListener` method.)

Answer (score 2):

The function getElementsByClassName will return you collection of html elements so use indexer to access each element returned.

var pleaseWork = document.getElementsByClassName('js primary medium btn');

```
for (var i = 0, length = pleaseWork.length; i < length; i++)
   pleaseWork[i].addEventListener('click', function(){alert('Boom!')});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your stack trace. The entire code seems to be executed by jQuery!

The following line returns an array (More details at [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName))

```
var pleaseWork = document.getElementsByClassName('js primary medium btn');
```

You will have to loop through them and attach the handlers on each of the items separately.

```
for (i = 0; i < pleaseWork.length; i++) { 
    pleaseWork[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Boom!');
   });
}
```

Hope this helps you.